# I am using MUI timePicker, but I am not able to select the minutes in that. It's getting closed down as soon as I select the hour. How to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, formik-material-ui

Sharing my code snippet below:

```
<DesktopTimePicker
      orientation="portrait"
      value={value ?? null}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          onBlur={onBlur}
          fullWidth
          sx={{ m: 1.5 }}
        />
      )}
    />
```

This is my function for handling timeChange,

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    onValueChange(date);
  };
```

How to fix this issue ?